# return value not getting logged from module exports

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a code that uses a library(jsforce) to query on Salesforce and get the records.

Currently, to keep the code clean, I'm separating the index and rest calls file. Here is my code.

```
var jsforce = require('jsforce');
const uName = 'myId';
const pwd = 'myPwd';
const servKey = 'myKey';

var conn = new jsforce.Connection();
var login = conn.login(uName, pwd, servKey, function (err, res) {
    if (err) { return false; }
    return true;
});
module.exports = {
    myCases: () => {
        console.log(`I'm called`);
        login.then(() => conn.query(`Select ID, Subject from Case where status='new'`, function (err, openCases) {
            if (err) { return console.error(err); }
            return openCases;
        }));
    }
}
```

and my index file is as below.

```
const restServices = require('./restServices');
var test = function () {

    restServices.myCases((err, data, response) => {
        console.log('err')
        console.log(err)
        console.log('data');
        console.log(data);
        console.log('response');
        console.log(response);
    });
}

test();
```

When I run it, my log prints only `I'm called` (from `restServices.js`). but none of the data from my `index.js` is printed.

also when I add a `console.log(openCases)`, it prints exactly the required data.

please let me know on where am I going wrong in returning the data and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To mycase pass an callback

Example in service.js

```
Mycase(callback) =>{
    // response, err from db then
    Callback(err, response) 
}
```

In index.js

```
Service.mycase((err, response) =>{
  Console.log (err,  response) 
}
```